# jQuery countdown week-long loop

Tags: jquery

How do I loop [Keith Wood's Countdown timer](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) on a weekly basis? With weekly basis, I mean that the timer should add 7 days each time it runs out. I tried coming up with this code but it doesn't work.

```
$(function () {
    var testing = new Date();
    testing = new Date(2013, 5, 24, 16, 0, 0);
    $('#nextCountdown').countdown({until: testing, timezone: +9, onExpiry: newWeek});
});

function newWeek() {
    testing.setDate(testing.getDate() + 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testing = new Date(testing.valueOf() + 604800000)
```

adds one week to timer

Comment: `$('#nextCountdown').countdown({until: new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 604800000)})` I do not know how to know, when the counter is triggered. Something like `($('#nextCountdown').countdown.onCounterZero(function(){$('#nextCountdown').countdown('destroy');
$('#nextCountdown').countdown({until: new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 604800000)});}`

Answer (score 0):

it must due to timeazone problem. Try to change the timezone. for example 2

```
timezone: +2,
```

plessase visit http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/9UQxq/

ie

```
<p id="defaultCountdown"></p>
<script>
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(2013, 5, 24, 17, 0, 0); 
//$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear, timezone: +2,onExpiry:newWeek});


function newWeek() {
    testing.setDate(testing.getDate() + 7);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. I changed the time so it leaves just a few sec before it's supposed to add the 7days, but it didn't work.